# How does this recursive call within a SetInterval function work?

Tags: javascript, recursion, setinterval

The following code is the solution to a challenge posted by the author of an online course I am taking. The goal is to continuously print the message "Hello World" (along with the delay time) in groups of 5 messages in which the delay increases by 100ms for each group. He posted an [explanation for this solution](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-timers-everything-you-need-to-know-5f31eaa37162#d7fb) (see Timers Challenge #4) in a Medium article, but it reads more like an approach than an explanation.

I have been able to use recursion successfully in other exercises and programs, but perhaps because I've never used in the context of the setInterval method, I'm just not following how it works in this situation.

*(Because this repeats indefinitely, I am not posting this as a runnable snippet.)*

```
let lastIntervalId, counter = 5;

const greeting = delay => {
  if (counter === 5) {
    clearInterval(lastIntervalId);
    lastIntervalId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('Hello World. ' + delay);
      greeting(delay + 100);
    }, delay);
    counter = 0;
  }

  counter += 1;
};

greeting(100);
```

I read his entire Medium article and also re-read a few articles on recursion, but I can't find anything that really applies to this use of recursion within a JavaScript timer.

It appears to me that if the log message is repeated in groups of 5, that the recursive call to `greeting(delay + 100)` would also be called 5 times, and that for each of those times another 5 recursive calls would be made, and so on exponentially.

If someone could explain to me step-by-step how this process actually plays out, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't get exploding exponential growth because one `setInterval` is never created without stopping the old one. `setInterval()` is always preceded by `clearInterval(lastIntervalId)`.

Even thought the `setInterval` function calls `greeting` each time it fires, most of the calls skip the `if` and just increment the `counter` and console log. This is what creates the behavior of groups of five.

Every 5th time the old interval is cancelled and a new one with a new delay is started and counter is reset. All other times the counter just increments.

Comment: Your explanation is helpful, but I still don't understand how `greeting(200)` is not called 5 times, and how each of those calls doesn't call `greeting(300)` 5 times, so the stack ends up with 5 greeting calls, then 5+25, then 5+25+125, etc.

Comment: Hey @PaulBrady, recursive function do kind of twist one's mind. `greeting(200)` *is* called five times, but 4 out of five of those skip over the `if` block because the counter doesn't equal five  — they just increment the counter  and return without in any further recursive calls.

Comment: Thank you @MarkMeyer! Your answer and additional comment about the `if` block made it all come together for me.